# Could not find or load main class jade.Boot

Tags: java

I have set the classpath for jade and my application jar file. When I type in the terminal java jade.Boot, the gui successfully loads. But when i try to start a peripheral container with  the command below i get:
error: could not find or load main class jade .Boot

java jade.Boot -container -host 192.168.153.129 r:jade.RequestAgent,s:jade.SearchAgent

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Maybe you should run it as `java -cp jade.jar jade.Boot....`

Comment: Found the error, must set the classpath in every terminal